# Why CURL --data-urlencode does not URL encode

Tags: curl

I'm trying to URL encode query parameters using `curl` with `--data-urlencode` but they end up being appended to the query like with `--data`.

The issue can be reproduced with the help of netcat and doing queries against it.

Example `curl` POST query:

```
curl --data-urlencode "foo=bar" 127.0.0.1:8080/test/path
```

Actual output:

```
$ nc -l 8080
POST /test/path HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo=bar
```

Expected output:

```
$ nc -l 8080
POST /test/path?foo=bar HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode), the `--data-urlencode` option "...posts data, similar to the other -d, --data options". So if you're seeing a post, that's the expected behavior.

You can use `--get` to make curl issue a GET request instead. Also, `-v` is a good friend!

```
curl -v --data-urlencode "foo=bar" http://127.0.0.1/test.php
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 7
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

With `--get`:

```
curl -v --get --data-urlencode "foo=bar" http://127.0.0.1/test.php
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.php?foo=bar HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
```

Comment: I later added explicit mention of that I want to do POST.

Comment: However, I do think your answer is correct and I had misunderstood that urlencoding meant encoding the data to the URL path but instead it means encoding the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to the body of the message.

Comment: Using the `--get` with `--request POST` has the desired effect of doing POST request with all the data encoded to the URL, but I have to say it feels quite confusing.